# Push Back com construtor de copia

Tags: c++

Eu não entendo porque quando crio um construtor de copia e faço um push back em um vector, ele chama o construtor mais de uma vez!

se eu fizer apenas 1 push back, ira mostrar 1 vez o construtor de copia.
se eu fizer 2 push back aumenta para 3.

Gostaria de saber também porque não posso usar && no construtor! foo(foo&& p){}

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class foo {
public :

foo(const foo& p){

    cout<<"Construtor de Copia"<<endl;
    }

    foo () {
    cout << "Chamando o Construtor " << endl ;
    }

    ~ foo () {
    cout << "Chamando o Destrutor " << endl ;
    }
};

int main ( int argc , const char * argv []) {

    vector < foo > v3 ;

    foo f1;

    v3.push_back(f1);
    v3.push_back(f1);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece pela necessidade de redimensionar o tamanho do `std::vector` devido ao `push_back()`, o que acarreta em cópias extras. Reservando espaço a priori, esse "problema" não ocorre.

```
vector < foo > v3 ;
v3.reserve(2);
```

Resultado:

```
Chamando o Construtor 
Construtor de Copia
Construtor de Copia
Chamando o Destrutor 
Chamando o Destrutor 
Chamando o Destrutor
```

> Gostaria de saber também porque não posso usar && no construtor!
>   `foo(foo&& p){}`

Não sou especialista nisso, mas até onde sei é possível sim. No caso, você estaria declarando um construtor de movimento ao invés de cópia. Para isso, é necessário utilizar `std::move`

```
v3.push_back(std::move(f1));
```